# Can not updated vbar_stack with stream data with python bokeh

Tags: python, stream, bokeh

There is my source code,
`x-axial` is time and others are data for `vbar_stack`.
In update function, `ds` is updated by `stream()`.
But `vbar_stack` didn't update.
Please help..

```py
i = 2
ds = ColumnDataSource({"x": ['0'], "d1": [0], "d2": [0]})
colors = ['red', 'green']
    
def update():
    global i
    i += 1
    ds.stream({'x': [str(i)], 'd1': [np.random.randint(1, 3)], 'd2': [np.random.randint(1, 3)]})

def bkapp(doc):
    p = figure(x_range=ds.data['x'], height=250)
    p.vbar_stack(['d1', 'd2'], x='x', width=0.5, color=colors, source=ds)
    doc.add_root(column(p))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)
```

Comment: Did you call `bkapp()`? If yes, did you get any kind of error massage?

Comment: Yes. But I couldn't find any error log..

Comment: Sorry, I had fixed some typo in my code..
x_range=ds['x'] -> x_range=ds.data['x']
But this issue didn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this.
I wrong understood about x-range.

```
ds = ColumnDataSource({'x': [0], "d1": [0], "d2": [0]})
...
p = figure(height=250)
...
ds.stream({'x': [i], 'd1': [np.random.randint(1, 3)], 'd2': [np.random.randint(1, 3)]})
```